# Can I get Romanian citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, romanian-citizens

My mom married my Romanian born step father in 2007. He is part of the family but we're not technically related.

I'm 18 and when they got married I was 9. My mom is not a Romanian citizen only a US citizen.

Could I still get Romanian citizenship by blood?

Comment: Are you currently resident in Romania? And if so, for how long?

Comment: How old are you/were you when they married? Is your mom a Romanian citizen now and through which procedure? I actually don't know about Romania but these details matter in other countries so it's probably useful to specify that.

Comment: I'm 18 and when they got married I was 9. My mom is not a Romanian citizen only a US citizen.

Comment: Also did your stepfather formally adopt you as a child?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can get it by blood, because your mother has only US citizienship.

You can get your Romanian citizienship if, either of these are true:

- you are adopted by your Romanian father
- you were born in Romania
- you give proof that you live in Romania (either by submitting a rental contract or buying contract) and must
- you promote Romania by special activities like sport, olympics, etc

This website is the National Authority for Citizienship and you can ask them there http://cetatenie.just.ro/index.php/ro/